# How to show arraylist data in recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have an ArrayList with repeated data, I want to show the first 5 items in the first row of recyclerview then the second 5 items in the second row, and so on. How can I achieve this in Recyclerview?

> Arraylist: [2013-04-01, OB Int. Updated upto 31/03/2013, 0, 0, 0,
> 2013-09-10, Cont. For Due-Month 082013, 780, 239, 541, 2014-03-28,
> Cont. For Due-Month 032014, 780, 239, 541, 2014-02-03, Cont. For
> Due-Month 012014, 780, 239, 541, 2013-07-26, Cont. For Due-Month
> 072013, 780, 239, 541]

**DataAdapter.java**

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private AppCompatActivity activity;
    List<String> data = new ArrayList();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private final View saparator;
        private final TextView txtLabel;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.txtLabel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.detail_parameter);
            this.saparator = itemView.findViewById(R.id.detail_value);
        }
    }

    public DataAdapter(AppCompatActivity activity, List<String> data) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        this.data = data;
    }

    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.pfpassbook_item, parent, false));
    }

    @SuppressLint("WrongConstant")
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.txtLabel.setText((CharSequence) this.data.get(position));
        holder.txtLabel.setTextSize(15.0f);
        holder.txtLabel.setTextColor(this.activity.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));

    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.data.size();
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView rcList;
    public String platenum = null;
    RelativeLayout idForSaveView;
    public static ArrayList<String> statement;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView((int) R.layout.pfpassbook);
        statement = (ArrayList<String>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("statement");
              setView();
        idForSaveView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relate);
    }

    private void setView() {
        this.rcList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.detail_recyclerview);
        this.rcList.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 5));
        this.rcList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        this.rcList.setAdapter(new DataAdapter(DetailActivity.this, statement));
    }

}
```

pfpassbook_item.xml

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    app:cardElevation="0dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/design_default_color_error"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/detail_parameter"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="2dp"
            android:paddingBottom="2dp" />
        

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Can you show please pfpassbook_item.xml file?

Comment: @Yeldar.N Question is updated... I want to implement approach of kelvin. But I am stuck how to set the array object.

Comment: You want to add each 5 data into one CardView?

Comment: Yes, First 5 data in first row/card then below that next 5 data and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't be in this kind of situation.
You can fix it BY converting this data to some ArrayList of Objects where object will hold 5 values .
This is just to get you started and give you idea.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HelloWorld {


    public static class Model {
        String value1;
        String value2;
        String value3;
        String value4;
        String value5;

        public String getValue1() {
            return value1;
        }

        public void setValue1(String value1) {
            this.value1 = value1;
        }

        public String getValue2() {
            return value2;
        }

        public void setValue2(String value2) {
            this.value2 = value2;
        }

        public String getValue3() {
            return value3;
        }

        public void setValue3(String value3) {
            this.value3 = value3;
        }

        public String getValue4() {
            return value4;
        }

        public void setValue4(String value4) {
            this.value4 = value4;
        }

        public String getValue5() {
            return value5;
        }

        public void setValue5(String value5) {
            this.value5 = value5;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Model{" +
                    "value1='" + value1 + '\'' +
                    ", value2='" + value2 + '\'' +
                    ", value3='" + value3 + '\'' +
                    ", value4='" + value4 + '\'' +
                    ", value5='" + value5 + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        String a[] = {"2013-04-01", "OBInt.Updatedupto31/03/2013", "0", "0", "0", "2013-09-10", "Cont.ForDue-Month082013", "780", "239", "541", "2014-03-28", "Cont.ForDue-Month032014", "780", "239", "541", "2014-02-03", "Cont.ForDue-Month012014", "780", "239", "541", "2013-07-26", "Cont.ForDue-Month072013", "780", "239", "541"};

        ArrayList<Model> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length ; i = i + 5) {
            Model m = new Model();

            m.setValue1(a[i]);
            m.setValue2(a[i + 1]);
            m.setValue3(a[i + 2]);
            m.setValue4(a[i + 3]);
            m.setValue5(a[i + 4]);
            arrayList.add(m);
        }

        System.out.println(arrayList.size() + "");
        
        for(int i =0 ;i<arrayList.size();i++){
             System.out.println(arrayList.get(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Provided that the size of the array will be in multiple of 5.
For me cleaning the data before setting to recyclerView is a good way to go as you can catch the errors before setting it on recyclerView.
Also by doing this you can use it in CustomAdapter to make desired View for your Items.

**UPDATE 1:**

**DataAdapter**

```
public class DataAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DataAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private AppCompatActivity activity;
    ArrayList<Model> data = new ArrayList();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView textView;
        private TextView textView2;
        private TextView textView3;
        private TextView textView4;
        private TextView textView5;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView)itemView.findViewById( R.id.textView );
            textView2 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById( R.id.textView2 );
            textView3 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById( R.id.textView3 );
            textView4 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById( R.id.textView4 );
            textView5 = (TextView)itemView.findViewById( R.id.textView5 );
        }
    }

    public DataAdapter(AppCompatActivity activity, ArrayList<Model> data) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(activity);
        this.data = data;
    }

    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MyViewHolder(this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.pfpassbook_item, parent, false));
    }

    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Model m = data.get(position);
            holder.textView.setText(m.getValue1());
        holder.textView2.setText(m.getValue2());
        holder.textView3.setText(m.getValue3());
        holder.textView4.setText(m.getValue4());
        holder.textView5.setText(m.getValue5());
    }

    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.data.size();
    }
}
```

**setViewMethod:**

```
private void setView() {
        this.rcList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.detail_recyclerview);
        this.rcList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL,false));
        this.rcList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        String[] a = {"2013-04-01", "OBInt.Updatedupto31/03/2013", "0", "0", "0", "2013-09-10", "Cont.ForDue-Month082013", "780", "239", "541", "2014-03-28", "Cont.ForDue-Month032014", "780", "239", "541", "2014-02-03", "Cont.ForDue-Month012014", "780", "239", "541", "2013-07-26", "Cont.ForDue-Month072013", "780", "239", "541"};
        ArrayList<Model> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length ; i = i + 5) {
            Model m = new Model();

            m.setValue1(a[i]);
            m.setValue2(a[i + 1]);
            m.setValue3(a[i + 2]);
            m.setValue4(a[i + 3]);
            m.setValue5(a[i + 4]);
            arrayList.add(m);
        }

        this.rcList.setAdapter(new DataAdapter(this, arrayList));
}
```

Model Class :

```
public  class Model {
    String value1;
    String value2;
    String value3;
    String value4;
    String value5;

    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public void setValue1(String value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }

    public String getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }

    public void setValue2(String value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public String getValue3() {
        return value3;
    }

    public void setValue3(String value3) {
        this.value3 = value3;
    }

    public String getValue4() {
        return value4;
    }

    public void setValue4(String value4) {
        this.value4 = value4;
    }

    public String getValue5() {
        return value5;
    }

    public void setValue5(String value5) {
        this.value5 = value5;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Model{" +
                "value1='" + value1 + '\'' +
                ", value2='" + value2 + '\'' +
                ", value3='" + value3 + '\'' +
                ", value4='" + value4 + '\'' +
                ", value5='" + value5 + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**pfpassbook_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You can design pfpassbook_item any way you want. always bind your data in Array of objects instead of adding one by one in the array.

Comment: I have updated my question with the code what i implemented till.

Comment: you want me to complete it for you?

Comment: I have created a class in which I am returning the array object but it not display on recyclerview.

Comment: I need your guidance. I am learning Android and JAVA.

Comment: The perfect solution for me. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use spanCount for showing desired quantity of items in a row like this

```
      layoutManager!!.spanCount = 5
```

And in XML inside your recyclerview like this

```
            app:spanCount="5"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `StaggeredGridLayoutManager` as the layout of recyclerview

> XML

```
 <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="+@id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.StaggeredGridLayoutManager"
        app:spanCount="5" />
```

Here `spanCount` defines the number of items you want to display in a row

If you want to define using class

```
val layoutManager = StaggeredGridLayoutManager(5, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
```